# name is not defined python

Tags: python, tkinter, discord.py

I defined prefixcmd in CONFING class, but when I call prefixcmd.get() it returns a NameError:
line 10, in 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefixcmd.get())
NameError: name 'prefixcmd' is not defined

Here is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
import os
import re
#==========BOT CONFING==========
class CONFING:
    PREFIX = '$'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefixcmd.get())
client.remove_command('help')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.statuses = cycle([playingBox.get(),'✨Robitco.ir'])
    change_status.start()
    print("Gangz Iz Herez")

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def change_status():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=next(client.statuses)))

#==================BOT RUN==========================
def StartBot():
 client.run(TokenBox.get())
 #================== TKINTER ========================
root = Tk()
root.title('Free Discord Bot maker ! [Beta] ')
root.geometry("400x400")

prefixLabel = Label(root, text="Prefix (NEEDED) Example: $ ")
prefixLabel.pack()

prefixcmd = Entry(root, width=30)
prefixcmd.pack()

spaceLabel = Label(root, text="---------------Token--------------")
spaceLabel.pack()

yourTokenLabel = Label(root, text="Enter Your Bot Token!")
yourTokenLabel.pack()

TokenBox = Entry(root, width=30)
TokenBox.pack()

RunButton = Button(root, text="Start Bot", command=StartBot)
RunButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It works when I use `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=CONFING.PREFIX)` instead of calling `prefixcmd.get()`

Comment: Where are you confused?  `CONFIG.PREFIX` is defined at that point; `prefixcmd` is not.

Comment: @Prune i want to use prefixcmd

Comment: You can use anything you want, so long as you define it first.

Comment: *"I defined prefixcmd in CONFING class"* is wrong, `prefixcmd` is not within `CONFING` class.  `CONFING` class has only one class variable `PREFIX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NameError: name 'prefixcmd' is not defined

`prefixcmd` isn't defined when you first call it here: `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefixcmd.get())`.

`CONFING.PREFIX` works because its defined before.

Comment: can you tell me how to use `prefixcmdd.get()` ?

Comment: You would have to define `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefixcmd.get())` after defining `prefixcmd = Entry(root, width=30)` and `prefixcmd.pack()`

`prefixcmd.get()` should then return whatever the user enters in the Entry widget.